# How do I port my hook_alter module to D8?

Tags: 8, hooks, wysiwyg

This is my D7 module (module name is ckeditor_show_blocks):

```
<?php

/**
 * Implements hook_ckeditor_editor_settings_alter().
 */
function ckeditor_show_blocks_ckeditor_settings_alter(&$settings) {
    $settings['startupOutlineBlocks'] = TRUE;
  }
```

All it does, it toggles Show Blocks by default on page load in the CKEditor when editing the page/node:

[image]

I'm trying to achieve same on D8. I did read some on hooks documentation, and it looked like same, so I didn't change anything, but the module won't apply when in editing mode, what I'm missing? Is hook format different? Does it have something to do with the fact that CKEditor is built-in feature in D8?

There is normal documentation on D7 on how to implement a simple hook module, but not so much about D8.

Comment: It might be hook_editor_js_settings_alter() in D8: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21editor%21editor.api.php/function/hook_editor_js_settings_alter/8.2.x

Comment: Hey @Jaypan thanks for reply, but no effect.

Comment: Did you clear your cache after changing the hook? If so, then yeah, it's probably not the same hook. It will have changed in D8 though, as it's no longer the ckeditor module, but part of core.

Comment: Yes, I did. Also there are two modules `editor` and `ckeditor` in `core/modules`, and the `$settings` I apply is from ckeditor, are you sure it's the `editor_js` in the hook to be used?

Comment: No, I'm not sure at all. That's why I put it as a comment, rather than an answer.

Comment: If the hook is `hook_ckeditor_editor_settings_alter` then the function is named incorrectly

Comment: Why `ckeditor_editor_settings_alter`? The module name is `ckeditor_show_blocks` and we are altering core module `ckeditor`. So it should be `function ckeditor_show_blocks_ckeditor_settings_alter(&$settings)`?

Comment: Yes, hooks are nothing but a naming convention. The implementing function has to be named MODULE_hook_name or the system won't be able to find it. As for "Why?", the comment in your code suggests so

Comment: But that's what I did.

Comment: The implementation of `hook_ckeditor_editor_settings_alter()` done in ckeditor_show_blocks.module is `ckeditor_show_blocks_ckeditor_editor_settings_alter()`, not `ckeditor_show_blocks_ckeditor_settings_alter()`.

Comment: @kiamlaluno how did you determine that, is there docu or some way to find the correct implementation? Anyway, I replaced it and it still does not work.

Comment: I was referring to the comment for your hook implementation (_Implements hook_ckeditor_editor_settings_alter()_). If that is the correct hook name, then your hook implementation is wrongly named. Replace _hook_ with the machine name of your module (*ckeditor_show_blocks*), and you get the correct name for your implementation. The CkEditor module, though, is looking for `hook_ckeditor_settings_alter()`. So, it's your comment that is wrong, not the hook implementation name.

Comment: See http://cgit.drupalcode.org/ckeditor/tree/ckeditor.api.php?h=7.x-1.x. Anyway, my comment was to make clear what @Clive was saying, not to suggest the correct Drupal 8 hook.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that the Editor module in Drupal core is the equivalent of the [Wysiwyg](https://www.drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) module for Drupal 7, and the core CkEditor module is the equivalent of the Drupal 7 module with the same name, I would say that the hook you are looking for is [`hook_editor_js_settings_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21editor%21editor.api.php/function/hook_editor_js_settings_alter/8.3.x) that, for a module whose machine name is ckeditor_show_blocks, it is implemented from the `ckeditor_show_blocks_editor_js_settings_alter()` function.

If you need to know the ID of the editor plugin used for a input format, you can get that from `$settings['editor']['formats'][$format_id]['editor']`; that is the case, for example, when you need to change settings if the used editor is the one implemented by the CkEditor module.

To make it clearer, the Editor module is the module that associate editors to the input formats used from a Drupal 8 site, while the CkEditor module in core contains an implementation of editor.

Comment: `startupOutlineBlocks` is called in CKEditor module not in Editor module so  I thought hook should be CKEditor's module. I tried your example and many other variations by now and nothing seems to work.